# Javascript click() function clicking all the buttons at the same time

Tags: javascript, function, click, clickonce

I want to click all the buttons at a website but my code tries to click all 2000 buttons at the same time and because of that chrome fails. How can I make it click one by one to the all buttons so it won't force the computer and chrome? I've thinked to count the index of the elements and have a for loop but I wonder is there any other ways or a basic code

```
const divs =
document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1');

divs.forEach(div => {

  div.click();

});
```

Chrome failed because of the overload

Comment: are they divs or buttons? in any case, all you need is to add a delay with `setTimeout`. have a look at the docs for it and you should be good to go

Comment: They are divs actually but the div bodies work like a button, I'll try setTimeout thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica I think `requestAnimationFrame` will make more sense here, since it will make sure current code queue is over, and in other hand will not wait any longer once the page is ready to action

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by `it will make sure current code queue is over`

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't figured this out yet, and as I mentioned in my comment you could use `setTimeout` for this.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.wbloks_1');
const ms = 10; // whatever delay value you want

divs.forEach((div, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => { div.click(); }, index * ms);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion for the task

```js
clickButton = (index) => {
  while(index < 2000) {
  document.querySelector('.wbloks' + [index]).click();
  clickButton(index + 1);
 }
 return;
}


----------
```

Comment: That makes the code more complicated, risks hitting too much recursion, and has the *same problem* as the original code.